# I reused a previous deposit address and the recipient claims the address was invalid

Tags: lost-transactions

I sent bitcoins to Sportsbook.ag, my Bitcoin wallet saved an address that I'd previously used to send Sportsbook.ag. The problem is my bitcoins never showed up in my account. I e-mailed sportsbook.ag, they told me that the address I used to deposit bitcoins was invalid and I had to contact my bitcoin wallet. From what I've seen the bitcoins aren't lost, they're somewhere, how do I get them?

Comment: You probably got scammed by them.

Answer (score 1):

If you've used this address before to deposit money to Sportsbook.ag, the address will still be under control of Sportsbook.ag. If they don't directly manage their Bitcoin deposits, their payment processor will still have received the payment in proxy.

They may not have expected you to reuse that address, but they should be able to fix it on their end. Contact them again and clearly explain what has happened. Good luck.

Comment: You should also have the transaction ID for both transactions - therefore proving you have sent the coins will not be an issue. Good luck!

Answer (score -2):

If your Bitcoins left your address and arrive onto address you don't control - then, well, you don't control them. And if the address is invalid, then most probably noone ever will be able to spend them.

Comment: The address is not invalid as the asker has used it before.